# How to adjust viewport clipping

Tags: 3d-view

I'm building a 3D model and it's huge but when I zoom out enough, it's clipped off sort of like when your camera clipping is too low. Is there a way to adjust the viewport clipping?
Reference image [here.](https://i.imgur.com/HDFozTf.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is in the right hand tool bar, under *View* tab. You can open it with <kbd>N</kbd> in Blender shortcuts or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> in Industry Standard shortcuts.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel stupid now for not doing that lol

Comment: How can I save the new value as the new default value? I have to re-type it everytime I open the viewport in a new window or a new project...

Answer (score 2):

In your viewport press <kbd>N</kbd>  to open the *Sidebar*.

Go to the *View* tab and adjust the *Clip Start* and *End* values.

Comment: Thank you so much. Should have been a duh lol