# Strange behaviour - object is hidden behind grey "wall"

Tags: texturing, materials, 3d-view, import

I bought a model that has .obj, .fbx and .max formats. I use Mac, so I'm not able to use .max, so I decided to import .obj in Blender. After I imported the file, I saw that a part of it hidden as if there was a gray wall or a portal to another universe. It's hard to explain it, better check the gif:

[image]

I'm totally new to Blender, so I have no idea what it is.

Comment: Most likely clipping https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance (search for others re viewport clipping as well as camera  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/152510/how-to-adjust-viewport-clipping  ) Quite likely the import is "too big" easy fix is to set a smaller scale when importing.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, setting of the clip end helped.

Comment: Re the solution posted, says set camera clip end, yet image says that didn't help.  The one on the left is the view, ie how far into view can see before it is clipped.  The camera clipping will be more evident in camera view or when rendering.   As mentioned your model is huge.  Try setting the bounds clamp when importing to keep it to a reasonable number like 10 (on the default grid).  IMO setting the clip to maximum is not the way to go.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does part of my model disappear when I zoom in on it in the 3D Viewport?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the "portal" was with the setting "Clip End" of the camera.

[image]