# Overlays Disappear

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I am new to Blender, so I don't really know how this works. I am following a tutorial and I have finished the model. I scaled up the model to around thirty meters and the grid has gone. I can only see the grid if my model is small, I also can see the grid if I use the side, front, or top view using the Numpad hotkeys. I can see the grid better when I get close to the world origin. I haven't switched off the overlays.

Comment: Could be the view port clipping (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/152510/how-to-adjust-viewport-clipping) but 30m should fit the default value of 1000m and not be clipped. Do you mean by "grid" the "floor" grid (x-y-axis) or the mesh of the object? Maybe you want to add a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object may be too large. If your scene resembles the image below, you may need to increase the Viewport Camera End Clip Distance. Press <kbd>N</kbd> in the 3D Viewport, and select **View** from the right-side tabs of the menu that appears. Clip distance is near the top:

[image: ClipDist]