# How I fix "sinking" clothes under body

Tags: modeling, sculpting, retopology

I was just going to unwrap my shirt in low poly after I was unwrapped the body in low poly, but I have a problem. The body is over the shirt, and I tried to inflate the shirt, increase object collision distance, scale it. When I zoom in a shirt is seen from the side. Also, I have in object properties in viewport display unchecked "in front" checkbox. Please, can somebody help?

[image: screenshot of clipped shirt]

[image: turnaround animation]

Comment: Object collision is only relevant for cloth physics. You can pull the shirt with the *Elastic Deform* brush in sculpt mode. Scaling it up or the *Inflate* brush should also work. If the *Inflate* brush makes the shirt deflate/shrink then the normals might be wrong/flipped?

Comment: https://1drv.ms/v/s!AiG5cVX8QE83tVm8MYVDujXoqb-T?e=ddLZlG  I tried the Elastic deform brush and inflate, but it turn out same like on this video.

Comment: Looks like the shirt gets clipped

Comment: yes, i tried now use knife tool in edit mode on body and it turns to normal as it should be. Hope, it solved the problem. Thank you so much for helping me. :)

Comment: you fixed it with the knife tool?! My guess was to lower the start value for the viewport clipping -> [How to adjust viewport clipping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/152510/how-to-adjust-viewport-clipping)

Comment: I just tried it and it looks normal i don't know but i have the old version with problem saved so, i can try your clipping. https://1drv.ms/v/s!AiG5cVX8QE83tWO76zkWh3X8Wp5E?e=6BxSG4